# Get replies of a tweet in Twitter API

Tags: twitter

I'm trying to get replies to a tweet by this endpoint:

> https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets?ids=1486331085881495&tweet.fields=author_id,conversation_id,created_at,in_reply_to_user_id,referenced_tweets --header 'Authorization: Bearer $ACCESS_TOKEN

but I get an error:

> When authenticating requests to the Twitter API v2 endpoints, you must use keys and tokens from a Twitter developer App that is attached to a Project. You can create a project via the developer portal

I've changed the permissions to Read, Write, and Direct Messages and regenerated the access token and secret.my app is under a project as well.

Keys and token in the developer app:

[image]

Any idea?